# Having trouble with a nested if/else statement. How do I get it to print the "else:" statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, input, integer

Here is the code:

```
# Write a program that asks the user how many people
# are in their dinner group. If the answer is more than eight, print a message saying
# they’ll have to wait for a table. Otherwise, report that their table is ready.

people = input("How many people will you be having in your dinner group? ")
people = int(people)

if people > 8:
    print(input("We'll have to put you on a short wait, is that okay?" ))
    if 'yes':
        print("Okay, we will call your table in the next 15 minutes.")
    else:
        print("Okay, we will see you another night, then. Thank you for stopping by.")
else:
    print("Perfect! Right this way; follow me.")
```

I'm not sure if my 2nd "if" statement is correct, because I want to make it so that if someone says "yes" and anything else in their sentence, or "yes" later in their sentence, then it will print that ("Okay, we will call your table in the next 15 minutes.") print statement.

Currently, if I type anything,(after answering the first question with any number above 8) even "no" it will still print the ("Okay, we will call your table in the next 15 minutes.") statement. I'd like the same thing for the "yes" explained above to happen for the "no" answer as well.

I tried putting 'yes' after the if, but I feel like I am missing something. Same for the 'else'.

Comment: `if 'yes':` Your condition is `'yes'`, literally. Think about what this means. You may want to _compare_ that string with something.

Comment: You have to compare the string with something. Your condition is currently just "yes", and that will be truthy all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the result of your input in a variable:

```py
choice = input("We'll have to put you on a short wait, is that okay?" )
if choice == 'yes':
    # Do something
else:
    # Do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't saving the value of the response to be able to check it in your second `if`:

```py
if people > 8:
    response = input("We'll have to put you on a short wait, is that okay?")
    if response == 'yes':
        print("Okay, we will call your table in the next 15 minutes.")
    else:
        print("Okay, we will see you another night, then. Thank you for stopping by.")
else:
    print("Perfect! Right this way; follow me.")
```